# Combine cloud-init autoinstall with other cloud-init modules

Tags: server, cloud-init

I'm trying to provision a VM with cloud-init and the server live image.
(I'm not using the cloud image, for infrastructural reasons I have to install from ISOs)

However, whenever I'm trying to combine `autoinstall` with e.g. `write_files`, the `write_files` part does not seem to succeed.

The following installs Ubuntu:

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  identity:
    hostname: boxy-001
    password: "$1$k46kl1..."
    username: alice
  storage:
    layout:
      name: lvm
  ssh:
    install-server: true
    authorized-keys: 
      - "ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2...."
     
write_files:              
- content: |              
    cloud_init_has_run    
  path: /cloud_init_flag
```

But the file is not written at `/cloud_init_flag`.

Are modules missing? Is cloud-config incomplete on the Server live ISOs?

**Edit** the file *is* written, but it's written in the installation environment! Instead, I should likely use the `autoinstall.user-data` key to provide the `user-data` for the target system.

Comment: Your `write_files` config works for me using the `20.04` live server installer.  Is the rest of the `autoinstall` working?  How are you confirming the file is missing?

Comment: So, when using this user-data while installing Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with the live installer, the `/cloud_init_flag` is actually created?

Comment: I took your `write_files` section and added it to my `user-data` file.  I started an install and opened a shell in the installer environment.  The `/cloud_init_flag` was created with the configured content.  My guesses: 1. your autoinstall file is not being used at all. 2. your autoinstall  file is invalid and not getting parsed.  3. you expect the file to be on the installed system when it is just on the installation environment

Comment: Aaah, that must be it. All cloud-init functions are executed in the install environment? Can I ask, how would I get cloud-init to run on the _installed_ system in combination with `autoinstall`?

Answer (score 7):

> how would I get cloud-init to run on the installed system in combination with autoinstall?

There is a `user-data` config [key for the autoinstall](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-reference#user-data) file.

For example, if you want your `write_files` configuration to be used by `cloud-init` on the **installed** system then this snippet could be included as part of the autoinstall file.

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  user-data:
    write_files:
    - content: |
        cloud_init_has_run
      path: /cloud_init_flag
...
```

**How it works**

- During the install, *subiquity* will create configuration for `cloud-init` at `/target/var/lib/cloud/seed/nocloud-net/user-data`.
- During the first boot of the installed system, `cloud-init` will use this config file to perform some of the install tasks.  Notably, this is how the first user is created.
- If a `user-data` section is included in the autoinstall file then *subiquity* will [merge the user-data section](https://github.com/canonical/subiquity/blob/2ddde49a436982716d1192538427ccd14eb9d32c/subiquity/models/subiquity.py#L197) into the generated `/target/var/lib/cloud/seed/nocloud-net/user-data` file.

Using the snippet above, the merged configuration resulted in this file content.

```
#cloud-config
growpart: {mode: 'off'}
locale: en_US.UTF-8
preserve_hostname: true
resize_rootfs: false
...
write_files:
- {content: 'cloud_init_has_run

    ', path: /cloud_init_flag}
```

During first boot, `cloud-init` did create the `/cloud_init_flag` file with the configured content.

Comment: Thank you. This would be a great addition to the concise documentation at https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-reference#user-data