# Installing packages via autoinstall vs user-data

Tags: system-installation, 22.04, cloud-init, user-data, autoinstall

I've read the entire [autoinstall documentation](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall) and the entire [cloud-init documentation](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), but I still don't understand the apparent overlap/redundancy between the ability to install packages in autoinstall, vs the ability to install packages via the user-data section.

What I want is to install packages and bake them into my image. I don't want to have to wait for packages to install when I clone the image.

[This post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1344472/combine-cloud-init-autoinstall-with-other-cloud-init-module) isn't specific to installing packages, but it opened my eyes to the fact that there's an "installation environment" and an "installed environment" (or is "target"  the better term?). I think it would help if I understood how this works.

Also related, I think, does "first boot" happen during the autoinstall procedure, or does "first boot" happen when I clone the image?

There are other redundancies between autoinstall and user-data... But I think it will help if I can better understand the things above.

For the record, I'm using packer to create templates in Proxmox.

Comment: @user535733 As far as I know, there's never any install media present. My process starts with Packer and ends up with a template in Proxmox. I never insert or remove installation media. I think that's part of my confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use an autoinstall configuration like this

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  packages:
  - cowsay
  user-data:
    packages:
    - rolldice
```

The package `cowsay` will be installed during the installation.  The package `rolldice` will be installed by *cloud-init* during first boot.

If the package goal is to "bake" the packages into the image then the method for `cowsay` should be used.

Anything in the `user-data` section gets used by *cloud-init*.  You can see it get put into `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-installer.cfg` on the installed system.

**notes**

- I also avoid using the `user-data` method because *cloud-init* will attempt to install or upgrade the package(s) during every boot.
- There is no significance to the packages in the example.  They are just tiny, simple, and easy to test with.
- I tested using Ubuntu 22.04 (`subiquity 22.04.2`).

Comment: I just came back to read this again and wanted to let you know it's one of the most well executed answers I've ever seen on SO. Well done.