# Combining autoinstall and cloud-init for 22.04?

Tags: server, cloud-init, autoinstall

Now that I got some understanding of the autoinstall, looking for more complex scenarios & unification for different server types.
How do I mix autoinstall for engaging headless automated bare-metal installation with cloud-init for advanced configuration?

An answer to [Installing packages via autoinstall vs user-data](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1473018) suggests inserting cloud-init into an autoinstall config like this:

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  ....
  #now comes the cloud-init part:
  user-data:
    packages:
      - sshfs
```

However, the autoinstall crashes with this.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it. Initially I inserted the cloud-init section in the middle of my autoinstall config. Now that I just put the user-data section after the autoinstall it started working. Still testing it though.